# Mouse Click inside OnTriggerEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Video URL for easy understanding - `http://tinypic.com/r/28jdyyq/9`

In this video, you can see my problem, when the sword touches the enemy.. enemy gets destroyed.. But i want when i mouseclick (or hit), then only ..enemy should destroy..

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);

        }
    }
```

This is my code, i have enemy and Player with sword (with collider) , everything is perfect, i want when i click mousebutton then only sword should kill enemy,

But, What is happening when i bring my player (with sword) near enemy and sword touches enemy, it is killing enemy without i hit by sword.

I tried the below code also by adding mouse click event inside Trigger , but nothing happens. Any idea Please

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){

                if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy"){

                    Destroy(col.gameObject);
                }

        }

    }
```

Here is code for Swing -

```
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("hit");
        }
```

Here hit is trigger in animation controller and make transition to the animation clip

Comment: i want to destroy enemy on mouse click. ( i have a player with sword and on mouseclick the player just swing the sword). i want when the sword hit the enemy on mouse click, then enemy should die. but with my first code, when i bring player near to enemy and sword touches (not hit) the enemy, it gets died.. i want enemy should die only when i mouseclick

Comment: no, sword is not having rigidbody. i can add it, but what next ?? then

Comment: yes, it is only the code. actually when i use the first code, the enemy gets destroyed.. i want enemy should destroy only on mouseclick..(means when player hit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Animation Events](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin-cDH1K_OAhVMiywKHXpRAaoQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.unity3d.com%2FManual%2Fanimeditor-AnimationEvents.html&usg=AFQjCNGJ16MgBQPkSHQFiI9THhumsgBE7Q&sig2=YtETD0GGHVbytMxB49QzGA&bvm=bv.129391328,d.bGg) to make true a Boolean when the sword rises in animation and turn it to false when the sword goes down and check that Boolean when OnTriggerEnter is called

make a variable like `hit` set it to **true** and **false** via **animation Event**

```
public bool hit;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {

        if (hit){

                if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy"){

                    Destroy(col.gameObject);
                }

        }
```